# How to get the visitors state information from the tab iframe tab page via signed request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

Is there anyway to get the state information of the user visiting my facebook tab page? Currently via signed request i can get the country information. Is there a way to get state information also??

Answer (score 0):

Answer is NO, check out the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

You get data like this

```
Array ( 
  [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 
  [issued_at] => 1328803958 
  [page] => Array ( 
    [id] => 114951721840 
    [liked] => 1 
    [admin] => 1 ) 
    [user] => Array ( 
      [country] => us 
      [locale] => en_US 
      [age] => Array ( [min] => 21 ) 
    ) 
)
```